# HTML canvas dynamically enter text boxes values into canvas on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Having three text boxes textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3 respectively

I want to put the values of these text boxes into a canvas (cnv) as user enter into text box

and delete the value as user delete it from text box.

The Problem is when I trying to delete the value of one textbox all the values from the canvas get cleared. But I want to prevent old values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event only gets fired when focus leaves the textbox.

For key-by-key responsiveness listen for the `keyup` event on your textboxes instead of the `change` event.

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var $text1=document.getElementById("sourceText1");
    var $text2=document.getElementById("sourceText2");

    $text1.onkeyup=function(e){ redrawTexts(); }
    $text2.onkeyup=function(e){ redrawTexts(); }

    function redrawTexts(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);   
        wrapText(ctx,$text1.value,20,60,100,24,"verdana");
        wrapText(ctx,$text2.value,150,60,100,24,"verdana");
    }

    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var lineHeight=fontSize;

      context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

      for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
        }
        else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      return(y);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Type text to wrap into canvas.</h4>
    <input id=sourceText1 type=text>
    <input id=sourceText2 type=text><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is okay but I want more then 1 textbox with the same functionality as you done. But the problem is when I try to insert another textbox the old text box value deleted...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include multiple text inputs.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Dhu6/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
var y=10
function canvasFillTxt(txt){
    ctx.fillText(txt,10,y);
    y=y+20
}
$('input').on('change',function(){
    canvasFillTxt($(this).val())
})
```

i hope is what you are looking for...